# How to set a max length on collection index in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, string-length

Using `Pymongo` to set/query/insert in my `mongodb` database.

It is possible to indicate that a value should be a unique index in mongodb.

```py
db.mycoll.create_index("sid", unique=True) # This is what I have so far
```

Now, I want to make sure that the index has **a minimum and maximum length**. (3-20 chars).

I didn't find any information about adding length restrictions, is it possible with mongodb ?

I would expect something like this:

```py
db.mycoll.create_index("sid", unique=True, max_len=20, min_len=3) # Is there a way to do this ?
```

---

If you need a bit more context, I have a collection in mongodb and for every document I need a `SID` (string ID). I would like to put a technical size limit on this value, so I can be sure on every side of my application that any string which doesn't match this size is not a proper id.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried schema validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699237/possible-to-specify-min-max-length-of-a-string-in-json-schema-v4

Comment: Not sure how to apply it in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to specify the maximum and minimum length of a string type field. For example,

```
db.createCollection("mycoll", {
    validator: {
         $jsonSchema: {
             bsonType: "object",
             required: [ "name", "city" ],
             properties: {
                 name: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     minLength: 3,
                     maxLength: 20,
                     description: "must be a string (3 to 20 chars) and is required"
                 },
                 city: {
                     bsonType: "string"
                 }
             }
        }
    }
} )
```

The `createCollection` method has the `validator` option where you can specify the [$jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/) to match the documents in the schema. Also, you can specify the `validationAction` (default is "error") and `validationLevel` (default is "strict") for the validator.

This means, if you try the following insert action, it will fail. The document will not be inserted, as the `name` field is only 2 characters in length.

```
db.mycoll.insertOne({name: 'mo', city: 'los angeles' })
```

**NOTE:**

- You still need to create a Unique Index on the `name` field to make sure it doesn't allow duplicate values.
- Schema Validation is applied on the database server - just like the unique  index.

[**EDIT ADD**]
**The PyMongo version:**

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['test']
db.create_collection('pycoll', validator={
         '$jsonSchema': {
             'bsonType': 'object',
             'required': [ 'name' ],
             'properties': {
                 'name': {
                     'bsonType': 'string',
                     'minLength': 3,
                     'maxLength': 20,
                     'description': 'must be a string (3 to 20 chars) and is required'
                 }
             }
        }
    }
)

print('Collection created...')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fits what I Want, Is it possible to call the `createCollextion` method in pymongo (python)? I didn't find it there  it says that `db["collection"]` create the collection...

Comment: There is a [create_collection](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=create_collection#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection) in PyMongo.

Comment: I have included in the answer - the PyMongo code example of using the _validator_ with `create_collection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this !